# How do I find specific information in a string?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have long strings with tags which don't follow a specific pattern.

However there are specific tags within the strings that I'd like to detect if present.

A couple of sample strings:

```
__tab1:technical-information-recycled-polyester, __tab2:size-guide-mens-football-tshirts, Archive, Gender:Men, Product - Men, Sport: Football
```

```
__label:new, __tab1:technical-information-polyester, Accessories, Gender:Men, Gender:Women, Gift, men, mens,  Mens Football, Mens Run,  Mens Winter, Product, Product - Men, Football, Run, Sport: Outdoor, Sport: Run,  Staples, Type_Accessories, unisex, winter, women, womens, Womens Football, Womens Run, Womens Staples, Womens Winter
```

As you can see - it's an absolute mess.

However, I want to try and pick up within the strings where they state "Gender: Men","Sport:Football", etc.

Then there is the additional issue that some are tagged with 2 Genders or 3 Sports.

I think my initial idea for a solution is using A LOT of case when's but I am hoping someone here has a more elegant solution.

Comment: use `LIKE` to look for patterns, e.g. `LIKE '%Gender:Men%'`

Comment: But you really should redesign this. Use an attribute-value table.

Comment: or at least a JSON object so JSON search functions can be used.